# Filtering and sorting log lines in PowerShell according to date string

Tags: powershell, filtering, streamreader

I have two separate scripts that do this process. First one looks at the large log and filters out specific lines from that long and puts them into a new log file. Then I have a second script that reads first ten characters of each line from that new log file (these actually represent the date of the log entry as yyyy-mm-dd), and based on that date, it puts that whole line of the log file into a new target file, whose name is based on that date (targetfile-yymmdd.log). Since my original logs tend to contain dates that span two or more dates, I need to sort them out so that each final log file only contains entries for one date, and so that the file name reflects that actual date.

I would like to consolidate these two scripts into one: read the line from the log, check if it matches the filter, if it does, check the first ten characters and then dump the line in the appropriate target file. Here are the basics, as I have them now:

Script 1 reads through a large log file (standard Apache htaccess log) and filters out lines based on a specific pattern, putting them in a new file:

```
$workingdate = [today's date as yymmdd ]
Get-Content "completelog-$workingdate.log" -ReadCount 200000 | 
foreach {
     $_ -match "(/(jsummit|popin|esa)/)" | 
     Add-Content "D:\logs\filteredlog-$workingdate.log"
}
```

Script 2 then goes through the new file and looks at the first ten characters from each line, which contain standard date as yyyy-mm-dd. It copies that line into a new file by the name targetfile-ddmmyy.log, where the date is based on the actual date from the line:

```
$file = "filtered-$workingdate.log" (where $workingdate is today's date as yymmdd)
$streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg "$file"
while($line = $streamReader.ReadLine()){
    $targetdate = $([datetime]::ParseExact($line.Substring(0,10), 'yyyy-mm-dd', $null).ToString('yymmdd'))
    $targetfile = "targetfile-$targetdate.log"
    $line | Add-Content $targetfile
}
```

Separetely, these two work well, but since my log file is over 20GB, I'd like to cut down on the time it takes to go through these logs (twice).

Comment: Do you want to retain `D:\logs\filteredlog-$workingdate.log` or just distribute the lines to `targetfile-$targetdate.log` ?

Comment: No need to keep the intermediate file. As long as I can go through the source, pick out the lines that match the RegEx string, and then put those lines into the appropriate target files based on those first 10 characters (representing date), I have no need for any other temp files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work with each matched line and skip creating the intermediate file.

```
(Get-Content "completelog-$workingdate.log" -ReadCount 200000) | 
%{ $_ } | ?{ $_ -match $REGEX } | %{
    $targetdate = '{0:yyMMdd}' -f $(Get-Date $_.Substring(0,10));
    $_ | Add-Content "targetfile-$targetdate.log"
}
```

Although I am not sure this will improve overall performance. Testing this on a 5MB file took about 100 seconds.

Comment: ah my bad, the %{ $_ } should come before the regex match

Comment: The leading `%{ $_ } |` in the 2nd line is obsolete. Where do you define `$REGEX` ? The Targetfile format is yyyy-mm-dd.  The `-ReadCount` parameter has to be inside the parentheses.

Comment: sorry, i'll fix the parenthesis. `$REGEX`, like `$workingdate`, is defined by OP. removing `%{ $_ }` gives me a conversion error from System.Object[] to System.DateTime.

Comment: @LotPings $Regex is assigned earlier (not showing here in the script). The targetfile format for the file name should be targetfile-yyMMdd.log. Each line in the source file begins with the date in the format yyyy-MM-dd